Return empty IEnumerable
Which is the newest way to return empty IEnumerable?
return Enumerable.Empty<ReportFileResult>();

or
return Array.Empty<ReportFileResult>();

or
return [];

This is the return type
IEnumerable<ReportFileResult>


Do you want to return an empty array, or an empty enumerable?

empty enumerable

The most explicit way to indicate that that is the intent, would be to use Enumerable.empty<ReportFileResult>();

FYI [] is just syntaxic sugar for Array.Empty (https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgAQCYBGAWACh8BmAAiJoGEaBvCm9u2hgbQF0aAsgAoAlDQC8APhp8A3BQC+QA==), and is the return value of Enumerable.Empty https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c21a1f603fb1f35649ff0c4c7d06de537770c642/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L15 So none of them is the best, as they are all exactly the same.

@JeremyLakeman Not necessarily: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgAQAYACfARhQG4BYAKHwGZSAmYgYWIG87jfSmAEgEMAzgAsAyjAAuAHjYA+YgFkAFAEpiAXiUBtALo1aAXyA===. It's target-type dependent.

Newest...? In a sense, [] is the most recent addition - but it is only new to the compiler, since in this case the compiler will just use Array.Empty<T>() for the implementation.
In terms of "best" (not what you asked, but a common question): there really isn't much in it, but the Array.Empty<T>() / [] approach is easy for code to type-test and detect emptiness without actually fetching an enumerator. But it is a tiny saving.

May I know this [] was introduced in which C# version? Is [] known as Collection literals introduced in C# 12?

@Steve "collection expressions", but: yes, C# 12

Not sure why I put [] in .net framework project and it can build with error

@Steve Add <LangVersion>12</LangVersion> or <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion> to the csproj; by default, the compiler langauge version is inferred from the target runtime, and .NET Framework is old (like: really old). You can, however, override the compiler to use a specific language version.

To return an empty IEnumerable<ReportFileResult> is
return Enumerable.Empty<ReportFileResult>();


You should use either backticks or code blocks (starting with four spaces) for code, otherwise generics disappear because they're interpreted as HTML elements.

The question was not "best". I also disagree that this is the "best" - in any way.

Can you please share an explanation why is this the best way, and secondly question specifies the newest way not the best way.

Because it is effective, consistent, and clearly stated, it will often return an empty collection. It minimizes memory consumption, stays away from pointless allocations, and simplifies the writing of the code.
secondly, it's my bad
